# Trace DNS query / answer with Event Tracing for Windows

Tags: windows, etw

Which ETW provider can be used to trace DNS queries / answers? I already tried Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client but it does not provide any data.

Comment: Just came across this looking for the same thing.  Sysmon seems interesting, but doesn't specifically hold this information.  I'll be performing much more research and will come back if and when I find an answer.

Comment: For now I've posted in [the technet forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/90da479c-88c2-4243-ad4d-463e249602d7/etw-provider-for-dns-questions-and-answers?forum=winserverPN).

Answer (score 0):

The provider is already available in Windows.  It can be accessed and started via:

1) event viewer\view menu\show analytics and debug logs

2) traverse event viewer tree: .\applications and services logs\microsoft\windows\dns client events\operational

You can gain more granular control on this by created an Event Trace Session:

1) compmgmt.msc\performance\data collector sets\event trace sessions\ right-click > new

2) Add providers> `Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client`

3) Properties> Keywords(Any)> Edit> check all and okay out of the config.

4) Right-click on the newly created trace session> properties> adjust as needed.  Try setting a stop condition then go back to file tab and check Circular.

I have confirmed that this provider contains DNS questions and answers, both returned by local cache and by server response.

Comment: This does only capture DNS queries but no DNS answers.

Comment: With the first method: DNS answers are contained in event IDs `3008` and `3020`.  Questions are contained in event IDs: `3006` and `3009`.  DNS cache responses are contained in event IDs: `3018`.

Comment: For the second method: review the results with `tracerpt -of xml` and look for `QueryResults` (some results may be empty, but you will get data).  You can also review the result using the old ETL client `xperfview`: http://i.imgur.com/59y5Gmn.png